# Why does changing server side cookie handling to use subdomain, break unity app

Tags: php, cookies, unity-game-engine, mono, setcookie

I work for the server team in a company, supporting a number of frontend devices.  We've recently begun changing our login code to support cross domain sessions.  However our Unity based App, simply stops setting cookies, once the domain= tag is part of the Set-Cookie header.  Does anyone one know why and what I could do to fix it?

In more details, the client makes a login call, and gets back this:-

```
Set-Cookie: Lb_CookieName=82qaa0bkbd53i42r6u1s01vqd5; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Then on the subsequent request, the client (the App) sends this header:-

```
Cookie: Lb_CookieName=82qaa0bkbd53i42r6u1s01vqd5
```

All good so far.

However when I implement our new code, and the login call gets back this:-

```
Set-Cookie: Lb_CookieName=cfn7finsa8uoumev3qovl54cs4; path=/; domain=ourdomain.com
```

The subsequent client call includes this:-

```
Cookie: Lb_CookieName=82qaa0bkbd53i42r6u1s01vqd5
```

Or if starting from a clean slate, no Cookies at all.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It does seem to work if the domain passed is full, so in the above example `rs.ourdomain.com`

Comment: Does `*.ourdomain.com` work for the main domain and subdomains?

Comment: Try using `.ourdomain.com`. That means the domain and all subdomains.

Comment: Interesting Barmar, you hit the nail on the head.  One of our App developers suggested I investigate the mono source, and I think I've found the problem.  Up until Mono 2.4 (Unity uses 2.0.5), it's expecting sub-domain style cookie domains to begin with a . Whereas the rfc concerned says it's been optional for some time.  Good to know.  Thanks